# Structural design of Shift Register in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation, shift-register

I've made a structural design of a shift register in vhdl . When WriteShift is 1 then I got shift and when it is 0 then shift register loads a price. Although load works perfectly when I set writeshift to 1 in testbench I get 00000 in simulation.

My code is the following:

```
entity ShiftRegis is
    Port ( Din : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           WriteShift : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
              reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
              En : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
end ShiftRegis;

architecture Behavioral of ShiftRegis is

component notGate 
    Port ( in0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           out0 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component nand4Gate 
    Port ( i0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           i1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           i2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           i3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           bitOut : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component D_FlipFlop 
    Port ( Din : in  STD_LOGIC;
           En : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
              reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           Clk : in  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal q4, q3, q2, q1, in3, in2, in1, in0, notWS : std_logic;

begin

ff4 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( Din => Din(4),
             En => En,
             Q => q4,
                reset => reset,
             Clk => Clock);

ff3 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( Din => in3,
             En => En,
             Q => q3,
                reset => reset,
             Clk => Clock);

ff2 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( Din => in2,
             En => En,
             Q => q2,
                reset => reset,
             Clk => Clock);

ff1 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( Din => in1,
             En => En,
             Q => q1,
                reset => reset,
             Clk => Clock);

ff0 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( Din => in0,
             En => En,
             Q => Q(0),
                reset => reset,
             Clk => Clock);

notg4 : notGate
    port map( in0 => WriteShift,
                 out0 => notWS);

nandg3 : nand4Gate
    port map( i0 => Din(3),
             i1 => notWS,
             i2 => WriteShift,
             i3 => q4,
             bitOut => in3);

nandg2 : nand4Gate
    port map( i0 => Din(2),
             i1 => notWS,
             i2 => WriteShift,
             i3 => q3,
             bitOut => in2);

nandg1 : nand4Gate
    port map( i0 => Din(1),
             i1 => notWS,
             i2 => WriteShift,
             i3 => q2,
             bitOut => in1);

nandg0 : nand4Gate
    port map( i0 => Din(0),
             i1 => notWS,
             i2 => WriteShift,
             i3 => q1,
             bitOut => in0);

Q(4) <= q4;
Q(3) <= q3;
Q(2) <= q2;
Q(1) <= q1;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: If you post your testbench, too,  someone else can reproduce your results.

Comment: Doesn't load either See [Detail A](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xVFmh.png). I guessed you were using an asynchronous reset (not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The cause is you're trying to use 4 input nand gates as 2:1 multiplexer for either the load input (Din) or shift input. You can't make a multiplexer out of just a nand gate. Also note that you can only get a '0' out when WriteShift and notWS are both '1' and the latter is the inverted value of the former. You could use 3 two input nor gates.

Comment: Where and when did you observed a value of 00000? The 4 input nand gates will give the value 11111 all the time (neglecting meta values) because `Writeshift nand not Writeshift = '1'`. And I expect that this value is loaded unmodified into the `D_FlipFlop` but you haven't disclosed its implementation. Please also show us your testbench, maybe the error is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load (WriteShift = '1' and en = '1') doesn't work either.

There's a design flaw where you're using 4 input NAND gates where you need a 2:1 Multiplexer for selecting between `Din` and `q` bits for the four LSBs in the shift register.

That's fixed by creating 2:1 muxes using three 2 input NOR gates:

```
architecture behavioral of shiftregis is

    component notgate 
        port ( 
            in0:    in   std_logic;
            out0:   out  std_logic
        );
    end component;

    -- component nand4gate
    --     port (
    --         i0:     in  std_logic;
    --         i1:     in  std_logic;
    --         i2:     in  std_logic;
    --         i3:     in  std_logic;
    --         bitout: out  std_logic
    --     );
    -- end component;

    component nor2gate
        port (
            i0:     in  std_logic;
            i1:     in  std_logic;
            bitout: out  std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component d_flipflop 
        port ( 
            din:    in  std_logic;
            en:     in  std_logic;
            q:      out std_logic;
            reset:  in  std_logic;
            clk:    in  std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal q4, q3, q2, q1, in3, in2, in1, in0, notws: std_logic;

    signal nor2g0a, nor2g0b: std_logic; -- ADDED
    signal nor2g1a, nor2g1b: std_logic; -- ADDED
    signal nor2g2a, nor2g2b: std_logic; -- ADDED
    signal nor2g3a, nor2g3b: std_logic; -- ADDED
begin

ff4:  
    d_flipflop
        port map (
            din => din(4),
            en => en,
            q => q4,
            reset => reset,
            clk => clock
        );

ff3:  
    d_flipflop
        port map (
            din => in3,
            en => en,
            q => q3,
            reset => reset,
            clk => clock
        );

ff2:  
    d_flipflop
        port map (
            din => in2,
            en => en,
            q => q2,
            reset => reset,
            clk => clock
        );

ff1:  
    d_flipflop
        port map (
            din => in1,
            en => en,
            q => q1,
            reset => reset,
            clk => clock
        );

ff0:  
    d_flipflop
        port map (
            din => in0,
            en => en,
            q => q(0),
            reset => reset,
            clk => clock
        );

notg4:  
    notgate
        port map (
            in0 => writeshift,
            out0 => notws
        );

-- norg3:
--     nand4gate
--         port map (
--             i0 => din(3),
--             i1 => notws,
--             i2 => writeshift,
--             i3 => q4,
--             bitout => in3
--         );

norg3a:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => din(3),
            i1 => writeshift,
            bitout => nor2g3a
        );
norg3b:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => notws,
            i1 => q4,
            bitout => nor2g3b
        );

nor3gc:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => nor2g3a,
            i1 => nor2g3b,
            bitout => in3
        );

-- norg2:
--     nand4gate
--         port map (
--             i0 => din(2),
--             i1 => notws,
--             i2 => writeshift,
--             i3 => q3,
--             bitout => in2
--         );

norg2a:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => din(2),
            i1 => writeshift,
            bitout => nor2g2a
        );
norg2b:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => notws,
            i1 => q3,
            bitout => nor2g2b
        );

nor2gc:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => nor2g2a,
            i1 => nor2g2b,
            bitout => in2
        );


-- norg1:
--     nand4gate
--         port map (
--             i0 => din(1),
--             i1 => notws,
--             i2 => writeshift,
--             i3 => q2,
--             bitout => in1
--         );

norg1a:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => din(1),
            i1 => writeshift,
            bitout => nor2g1a
        );
norg1b:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => notws,
            i1 => q2,
            bitout => nor2g1b
        );

nor1gc:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => nor2g1a,
            i1 => nor2g1b,
            bitout => in1
        );

-- norg0:
--     nand4gate
--         port map (
--             i0 => din(0),
--             i1 => notws,
--             i2 => writeshift,
--             i3 => q1,
--             bitout => in0
--         );

norg0a:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => din(0),
            i1 => writeshift,
            bitout => nor2g0a
        );
norg0b:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => notws,
            i1 => q1,
            bitout => nor2g0b
        );

nor0gc:  
    nor2gate
        port map (
            i0 => nor2g0a,
            i1 => nor2g0b,
            bitout => in0
        );

    q(4) <= q4;
    q(3) <= q3;
    q(2) <= q2;
    q(1) <= q1;

end architecture behavioral;
```

And that gives:

[image: shifregis_tb_fixed.png]

Where you see on q(0) that between A and B a '0' is output, B and C a '1, C and D a '0', D and E a '1' and E and F a '1', following that the shifted in values for Din(4), because there's no mux on the din input to ff4.

You'll notice the LSB goes out first.

Repetitively instantiated components can in general be a target for the use of generate statements.

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I had to guess and settled on an asynchronous reset for the D_flipflop component.

Comment: Yes, the `nand4gate` must be replaced by a multiplexer. But, this doesn't explain why the OP observes a value of 00000 if `Writeshift` is set to 1. There is either an error in the testbench or the components do not behave as their names suggest.